# Get number of subscribers of YouTube channel

Tags: youtube-api

In former times I used

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME?v=2&alt=json

to get the number of subscribers for certain users. A month ago Google disabled that old API. Is there an alternative now which doesn't make use of an API_KEY?

Answer (score 1):

If you like a **very ugly** solution ( or you may work on it ), you can use [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql).

replace `url` with the one you have

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select div from html where url="https://www.youtube.com/user/Computerphile"&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=
```

and then fetch number of subscriber from the json string

**example in python**

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> r = requests.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select div from html where url="https://www.youtube.com/user/Computerphile"&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=')
>>> res = json.loads(r.text)
>>> res ["query"]["results"]["body"][3]["div"]["div"][3]["div"]["div"][4]["div"]["div"][0]["div"]["div"][1]["div"]["span"]["span"][0]["content"]
u'409,045'
```

You can use regex:

```
>>> re.findall('"content":"(\d+(,\d*)*?)"',r.text)
[(u'409,045', u',045')]
```

and then extraxt the first group.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [subscriptions.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it) to get the list of subs via the API explorer. See the `mySubscribers` field.

Comment: Can you explain a little further?  I tried this with a few different channels I follow, and it never returned a count, just a total results = 0, and results per page = 5